# Trying to print out some sequence of numbers

Tags: java

I want to print out a sequence of numbers using this formula

- Enter a number
- if number is even divide number by 2.
- But if number is odd multiply number by 3 and add 1
- continue doing this until number becomes 1

sample input=3
Sample output=10 5 16 8 4 2
this is what I tried but still not getting it

```java
package victor;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class proj {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner put=new Scanner(System.in);
   int temp=0;
   boolean notOne=true;
   System.out.println("input::: ");
   int num=put.nextInt();
   while(temp!=1){
   if (num%2==0){
     temp=num;
     System.out.println(temp/2);
     break ;
   }
   else {
   temp=num;
     System.out.println(temp*3+1);
     break;
   }
   }
   if(temp!=1){
     notOne=false;
   }
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Ah yeah. Good old [Collatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture). Anyway... you forgot to ask an actual question. Please [edit] the post, format the code properly and ask a specific question.

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Class names should start with upper case letter.

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because you keep re-assigining the variable `temp` to the initially scanned `num`.

You keep checking if the initially scanned `num` is odd or even, when you should check if `temp` is odd or even.

You also `break` out of the loop for no reason.

And finally, you're not saving the result of the operations, you're only printing out the result.

Try to understand the points I mentioned above by noticing the differences between your code and the following:

```
while(temp!=1){
   if (temp%2==0){
     temp = temp/2;
   }
   else {
     temp = temp*3+1;
   }
   System.out.println(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating the value of temp. You are just printing it. Take the following statement

```
   if (num%2==0){
     temp=num;
     System.out.println(temp/2);
     break ;
   }
```

Here you are setting temp to num and just printing temp/2 and never setting a value.

I wrote my version of it which is a bit more simpler. I hope this will help you. You can create a string to get a better output of course.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number:");
        int number = scan.nextInt();

        while (number != 1) {
            number = number % 2 == 0 ? number / 2 : ((number * 3) + 1);
            System.out.println("Number became " + number);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Starting...");
        
        //Lets start the program, first we need
        //the Scanner class to access to the input
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Type a num: ");
        //I dont use: nextInt() because when asking for another input, will scan only
        //the rest of the line (Maybe just \n - line break )
        int num = Integer.parseInt(stdin.nextLine());
        
        //Optional 
        int loops = 0;
        
        while(num!=1){
            
            //Pair, so num/2
            if ( num %2 == 0){
                num/=2;
            }
            else{
                //num*3 +1
                
                num=num*3 +1;
                //Note that:
                //1 + num*3
                //Doesnt alter the result
            }
            
            System.out.println("num: "+num);
            loops++;
        }
        
        System.out.println("total loops: "+loops);
    }
}
```